# Regex Match Numeric in URL

Tags: regex

I am trying to setup a tracking script which hits on a url. However I am lost on how to ignore the number in the url.

For example - the url is `/account/checkout/21212/complete`

Where `21212` is always random or changing, how can I match the URL with regex even with the changing `21212` number?

Something like `/account/checkout/regex number/complete`

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: `\/account\/checkout\/\d+\/complete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\d` to match a digit, with `+` to match one or more occurrences:

```
/account/checkout/\d+/complete
```